# ReactJS "eating" my onClick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm doing a ReactJS web app, and everything seems to be doing good... except for one silly thing that I can't figure out why is happening.

I'll try to reduce to the minimum implementation necessary.

I've an Item component: http://pastebin.com/P8T6vAhR

A container, which renders the List and defines the function properly: http://pastebin.com/GmyrnY2c

And a List component which renders each of the items and pass the function as a parameter (after receives it from the Container): http://pastebin.com/6cwPCJhn

The function seems to be fine, and I can see that the function is there when I ask for log it on the console.

But then what I got rendered instead is:

```
<button class="ui">My Category</button>
```

Hey, where's the onClick attribute? It's gone... no idea why.
Probably is some stupid mistake or misunderstanding about the magic behind JSX, but I can't find the problem... specially because I use similar things on other parts of my code, and everything else is working nicely.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Urgh... first of all, why using jQuery when using React? You don't need it if you are using React properly.

Comment: can you try removing all the code from the onClick function and put just a log or alert?

Comment: @Maggie Good to know, it's my first time coding using ReactJS, you mean I can just use change the State and update the component according?

Comment: @Maggie Thanks, with this change I could see that I'm probably looking into the wrong place... the onClick is still not there, but it works (show the alert), so my error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to control the component just by using state and props. You shouldn't need to manipulate DOM directly when using React. In order to get the reference to the component like you would using jQuery's $(#id) have a look at refs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: As to the second question, have a look at the "event delegation" section: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

I believe you'll never be able to see onClick attribute as a part of the generated DOM node.

Comment: There's no error here. It's working exactly as it should. The `onclick` attribute is a way to get some code into the `click` event handler of the DOM element. React bypasses that entire step and attaches the function to the click handler directly. No need to affect the markup.

Comment: As someone who was interested in possibly answering your question: put your code in your question. It is nowhere-near long enough to require pastbins, inline it so we can see what you're doing instead of spending expensive time look up your pastebins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hey, where's the onClick attribute

The `attribute` is just converted to a *property* that gets passed to the component.

The *dom onclick* is not the same as the component `prop` (react does fancy event delegation which performs better and doesn't suffer from `onclick` global scope).